# Mock ItemCollection<QueryOutcome> using Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have to write unit test case using mockito for the below code

```
QuerySpec querySpec = new QuerySpec()
                .withKeyConditionExpression(EXPRESSION)
                .withValueMap(
                        new ValueMap()
                                .withString(ID_PLACEHOLDER, workItemId));
ItemCollection<QueryOutcome> items = index.query(querySpec);
List<Record> recordsList = new ArrayList<>();
for(Item item: items) {
     recordsList.add(gson.fromJson(item.toJSON(), Record.class));
}
return recordList;
```

I can see similar answer using easy mock [How to mock DynamoDB's ItemCollection<QueryResult> using EasyMock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30990653/how-to-mock-dynamodbs-itemcollectionqueryresult-using-easymock). How to do write unit test case for the function above using mockito?

Comment: Don't mock values. Just make a real `ItemCollection` and return it.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- can you provide an example on how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
  private Item getItem() {
    Item item = new Item();
    item.with("year", "2024");
    item.with("month", "02");
    item.with("day", "01");
    item.withBoolean("tagged", false);
    item.with("report_creation_date", "2024-02-01T10:23:25Z");
    return item;
  }

@Test
public void testGetMetaData() throws Exception {
    Table table = Mockito.mock(Table.class);
    // ItemCollection<QueryOutcome> items = Mockito.mock(ItemCollection.class); // doesn't work
    ItemCollection<QueryOutcome> items = new ItemCollection<QueryOutcome>() {
      @Override
      public Integer getMaxResultSize() {
        return null;
      }

      @Override
      public Page<Item, QueryOutcome> firstPage() {
        List<Item> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(getItem());
        QueryOutcome queryOutcome = new QueryOutcome(new QueryResult().withItems());
        return new Page(list, queryOutcome) {
          @Override
          public boolean hasNextPage() {
            return false;
          }

          @Override
          public Page nextPage() {
            return null;
          }
        };
      }
    };
    metadataService.setTable(table);
    when(table.query(any(QuerySpec.class))).thenReturn(items);

    // assert that the item values are same, or log these values and assert using log appender.
```

[How to do a JUnit assert on a message in a logger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827677/how-to-do-a-junit-assert-on-a-message-in-a-logger)

```
  }
```

Page takes in two parameters, Item and QueryOutcome; item is the entity or record, so initialize a list of that.
QueryOutcome can be initialized with new QueryResult().withItems().

I am using table.query so change as per your index.query.

Answer (score -1):

```
ItemCollection<QueryOutcome> items = mock(ItemCollection.class);
when(index.query(any(QuerySpec.class)).thenReturn(items);
```

The above code can do what you want, but I don't see why you would want to mock ItemCollection in this case. Rather return a real ItemCollection with values that you've manually inserted as below>

```
ItemCollection<QueryOutcome> items = new ItemCollection<>();
items.add(...)
when(index.query(any(QuerySpec.class)).thenReturn(items);
```

Comment: ItemCollection is abstract and cannot be initialized when returning a real itemcollection with values.